# SDK for QS pda 3505

Tags: printing, sdk

i have purchase a QS pda 3505 android device which has a scanner and a thermal printer, my problem is i need the sdk and also the codes that will help me print through the printer.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but you can get the SDK and example files from http://www.qsprinter.com/download.html

Direct link grabbed from the above site:
http://www.qsprinter.com/ufile/75040aed8bd95d668ab0cc5cb5042f4c.7z

You will get android project source code which you can import into Android Studio.

**Example for accessing printer:**

```
    // first declare `printerClass`
    Public static PrinterClassSerialPort printerClass=null;
```

then onResume:

```
    printerClass=new PrinterClassSerialPort(new Handler());
    printerClass.open();
```

printing some text:

```
    printerClass.printText(str);
```

There is also function for printing `Bitmap`s using `printerClass.printImage(bitmap)`

The above code was not tested and taken from the above website's PDF document about the JAVA API which can be found at http://www.qsprinter.com/ufile/adb6bd0043d705d50363d2bb04dbac24.pdf

Comment: Just added more content.